# How to alter node links

Tags: 8

I have few existing node nodes which contains link `<a href="/some/link/here">Click here</a>`. Now I want to update all links to `<a href="/updated/some/link/here">`. Is there any way to do this in Drupal8 via code.

Comment: Why not just edit the nodes and change the link? Is this link created with a field type of Link?

Answer (score 0):

You can load all those nodes by nid with

```
node_load_multiple(array $nids = NULL, $reset = FALSE);
```

Loop over all nodes and then find and replace by using

```
str_replace('original link', 'new link', $node->field_you_want_to_change);
```

And then saving the node using

```
$node->save()
```

Comment: **Note:** [node_load_multiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/8.2.x) in Drupal 8.x, will be removed before Drupal 9.0. Use [\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AloadMultiple/8.2.x).

Comment: True but this module will be used once so in my opinion it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: @fons Vandamme Thanks. Is there any way I can change it on the fly. I dont want to update the entries in database instead want to change it while rendering. I have a multi site shares same DB. For one site I want to show the same content body and for other I want all links to be updated with '/something'

Comment: See Robin his answer for the solution on that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the content of your node, without changing it in the DB, with

[hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter/8.2.x) or [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.2.x)

Both these hooks allow you to alter the content of your entity before it is rendered. In combo with Fons' answer you can then replace your old link with the new one.